# R from SpatialPointsDataFrame to SpatialLines

Tags: r, line, point, spatial

I'have a SpatialPointsDataFrame load with

```
pst<-readOGR("/data_spatial/coast/","points_coast")
```

And I would like to get a SpatialLines in output, I have find somthing

```
coord<-as.data.frame(coordinates(pst))
Slo1<-Line(coord)

Sli1<-Lines(list(Slo1),ID="coastLine")
coastline <- SpatialLines(list(Sli1))
class(coastline)
```

it seems to work but when I try plot(coastline) , I have a line that should not be there ...
[image: a bad coastline]

Some one can help me ? [The shapefile is here](http://dl.free.fr/geDukHanh) !

Comment: I see the file 'points_coast.zip', but cannot figure out how to download it.  What do you click to download the file?

Comment: How many lines? The points need to be organized not justvstrung together. Are there attributes with the points specifying ID to line and/or ordering within line?

Comment: To download, click `valider et telechargez le fichier`.

Comment: Thank koekenbakker for the small howto :-) . @ mdsumner : I would like one line... but I've got more than 4000 points../

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have looked at the shapefile. There is an `id` column, but if you plot the data, it seems that the id is not ordered north-south or something. The extra lines are created because the point order is not perfect, connecting points that are next to each other in the table, but far from each other in terms of space. You could try to figure out the correct ordering of the data by calculating distances between points and then ordering on distance.

A workaround is to remove those lines that are longer than a certain distance, e.g. 500 m.. First, find out where distance between consecutive coordinates is larger than this distance: the `breaks`. Then take a subset of coordinates between two `breaks` and lastly create Lines for that subset. You end up with a coastline consisting of several (`breaks-1`) segments and without the erroneous ones.

```
# read data
library(rgdal)
pst<-readOGR("/data_spatial/coast/","points_coast")
coord<-as.data.frame(coordinates(pst))
colnames(coord) <- c('X','Y')

# determine distance between consective coordinates
linelength = LineLength(as.matrix(coord),sum=F)
# 'id' of long lines, plus first and last item of dataset
breaks = c(1,which(linelength>500),nrow(coord))

# check position of breaks
breaks = c(1,which(linelength>500),nrow(coord))

# plot extent of coords and check breaks
plot(coord,type='n')
points(coord[breaks,], pch=16,cex=1)

# create vector to be filled with lines of each subset
ll <- vector("list", length(breaks)-1)
for (i in 1: (length(breaks)-1)){
    subcoord = coord[(breaks[i]+1):(breaks[i+1]),]

# check if subset contains more than 2 coordinates
    if (nrow(subcoord) >= 2){
        Slo1<-Line(subcoord)
        Sli1<-Lines(list(Slo1),ID=paste0('section',i))
        ll[[i]] = Sli1
    }

}

# remove any invalid lines
nulls = which(unlist(lapply(ll,is.null)))
ll = ll[-nulls]
lin = SpatialLines(ll)
# add result to plot
lines(lin,col=2)

# write shapefile
df = data.frame(row.names=names(lin),id=1:length(names(lin)))
lin2 = SpatialLinesDataFrame(sl=lin, data=df)
proj4string(lin2) <- proj4string(pst)
writeOGR(obj=lin2, layer='coastline', dsn='/data_spatial/coast', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

[image: coastline]

Comment: Thank's koekenbakker !! it works so great! An small question ... how can I writeOGR ?